# Pandas pivot table rename index not working

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am creating a pivot table using the below code.

```
# Creating DF for Functional Range in Mode1
df_thd_funct_mode1 = df_thd_funct[(df_thd_funct['Supply'] == 2.5) | (df_thd_funct['Supply'] == 2.7) | (df_thd_funct['Supply'] == 3.6)]
df_thd_funct_mode1_copy = df_thd_funct_mode1
# df_thd_funct_mode1.head()


df_thd_funct_mode1_PVT = pd.pivot_table(df_thd_funct_mode1 ,index = ['0.0189','0.0378','0.1194','0.2159','0.3768','0.5925','0.9318','1.0711','1.1890'],values = ['Temp', 'xvalues','Supply'])
df_thd_funct_mode1_PVT.rename(columns={'0.0189':'94','0.0378':'100','0.1194':'110','0.2159':'115','0.3768':'120','0.5925':'124','0.9318':'128','1.0711':'129','1.1890':'130'}, inplace=True)
# df_thd_funct_mode1_PVT.iplot()

df_thd_funct_mode1_PVT
```

you can see that I am renaming the index using the code below.

```
df_thd_funct_mode1_PVT.rename(columns={'0.0189':'94','0.0378':'100','0.1194':'110','0.2159':'115','0.3768':'120','0.5925':'124','0.9318':'128','1.0711':'129','1.1890':'130'}, inplace=True)
```

But the code is not working.I am getting the pivot table as shown below.May I know where I went wrong.

```
                                                              Supply    Temp
        0.0189  0.0378  0.1194  0.2159  0.3768  0.5925  0.9318  1.0711  1.1890      
        0.0116  0.0081  0.0105  0.0977  0.3308  0.3072  0.2436  0.2373  0.7829  2.5 -40
        0.0122  0.0071  0.0128  0.1372  0.3568  0.3279  0.3040  0.3107  0.3251  3.6 -40
        0.0079  0.0113  0.0438  0.3175  0.3077  0.2895  0.2868  0.2643  2.7 -20
        0.0124  0.0091  0.0132  0.1125  0.3831  0.3589  0.2723  0.2393  0.3450  2.5 0
        0.0125  0.0074  0.0134  0.1608  0.3966  0.3632  0.3295  0.3280  0.3244  2.7 -20
```

[image]

Comment: Please give a reproduciable example

Comment: updated the question.Could you please check

Comment: Sorry, but this is not an example I can easily copy and reproduce. Give it in code format

Answer (score 0):

If you want to rename index values ​​you should use this:

```
df_thd_funct_mode1_PVT.rename(index={'0.0189':'94','0.0378':'100','0.1194':'110','0.2159':'115','0.3768':'120','0.5925':'124','0.9318':'128','1.0711':'129','1.1890':'130'}, inplace=True)
```